# How to filter on master table in a left join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables  POST and COMMENT,
each post has ID, TITLE, CATEGORY_ID AND USER_ID
each comment has ID, COMMENT, POST_ID AND USER_ID

I want to list all posts having category_id=2 and comment.user_id=1

```
CREATE TABLE post
    (`ID` int, `TITLE` varchar(9), `CATEGORY_ID` int, `USER_ID` int) 
;

INSERT INTO post
    (`ID`, `TITLE`, `CATEGORY_ID`, `USER_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 'My post A', 1, 1),
    (2, 'My post B', 2, 1),
    (3, 'My post C', 2, 2)
;

CREATE TABLE comment
    (`ID` int, `COMMENT` varchar(12), `POST_ID` int, `USER_ID` int)
;

INSERT INTO comment
    (`ID`, `COMMENT`, `POST_ID`, `USER_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 'My comment X', 1, 1),
    (2, 'My comment Y', 2, 1),
    (3, 'My comment Z', 1, 2)
;
```

This command fetch all posts including the one with category_id = 1

```
    SELECT post.*, comment.comment, comment.post_id, comment.user_id c_user_id
FROM post
LEFT JOIN COMMENT
ON POST.id = COMMENT.post_id
AND COMMENT.user_id=1
AND POST.category_id =2
```

I get this

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| USER_ID |   TITLE   | CATEGORY_ID | USER_ID |   COMMENT    | POST_ID | C_USER_ID | 
+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| 1       | MY POST A | 1           | 1       | null         | null    | null      | 
| 2       | MY POST B | 2           | 1       | My Comment Y | 2       | 1         |  
| 1       | MY POST C | 2           | 2       | null         | null    | null      | 
+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

and I'd like to get this  (all  posts with category_id = 2  so 2 records,  where the comment for user_id appears  and the other comment to null as below:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| USER_ID |   TITLE   | CATEGORY_ID | USER_ID |   COMMENT    | POST_ID | C_USER_ID |  
+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| 2       | MY POST B | 2           | 1       | My Comment Y | 2       | 1         | 
| 1       | MY POST C | 2           | 2       | null         | null    | null      |  
+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rule about putting conditions in the `on` clause for `left outer join`s . . . well, it applies to conditions on the *second* table, not the *first*.  So, put that condition in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT post.*, comment.comment, comment.post_id, comment.user_id c_user_id
FROM post LEFT JOIN
     COMMENT
     ON POST.id = COMMENT.post_id AND COMMENT.user_id=1
WHERE POST.category_id = 2;
```

The way the `left outer join` works, conceptually is to say:  Take a row in the first table.  Then find all matching rows in the second table subject to the `on` condition.  Keep all the matches.  If there are no matches, *keep* the row in the first table.

Guess what.  This is still the logic, even when the condition filters rows on the first table.  So, filtering a `left outer join` on conditions in the first table has no effect.

All of this similarly applies to `right outer join`s with all the table references reversed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , exactly what I wanted  @GordonLinoff